# Como ir para uma parte de um texto na mesma página clicando num link em cima

Tags: xhtml

Imaginem uma página com muito texto. O que quero fazer é tornar uma palavra clicável que quando o usuário clica vai para um outro texto na mesma página.

Quero fazer isto usando XHTML e CSS.

Tenho mais ao menos uma ideia de que no XHTML é usado # mas não me lembro como se faz.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Se chama **anchor link**

Exemplo com div:

```
<div id="tips">Useful Tips Section</div> <!-- crie um ID para a div ou span -->
```

Ou com outro link:

```
<div id="tips">Useful Tips Section</div>
```

Chamando outro link para a posição da div ou do link anterior:

```
<a href="#tips">Visit the Useful Tips Section</a> <!-- Utilize esta Id com # no link para ir até este local -->
```

Chamando o link em outra página:

```
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com/html_links.htm#tips">Visit the Useful Tips Section</a>
```

Aqui você precisa passar a url completa do site, porque você está usando em outro local, outro site, etc, mas funciona, vai apontar exatamente para a `div id = "tips"`

Fonte:http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp

Comment: Desculpe mas não entendi. Por exemplo quero fazer que a palavra marcelo seja um link e que ao ser clicada vá para uma parte do final da mesma página que diz aymone. Como faço isso no xhtml e no css?

Comment: Você vai encapsular a palavra que você quer dentro de uma div ou outro elemento, como um span, vai atribuir um ID para este span ou div.
depois você cria um link comum, com a propriedade href='#id' do span ou div, etc.

Answer (score 6):

```
<section id ="top">Texto</section>

<a href="#top">Clique aqui</a>
```

O link vai para a section.

Answer (score 4):

Basta, por exemplo, usando `section` para colocar o texto que pretende linkar e colocar um `id` nessa `section`:

```
<section id="minhaTag">
    <!-- o meu texto -->
</section>
```

Depois é só usar esse `id` na palavra de referência para o texto:

```
<a href="#minhaTag">Palavra de link para o texto</a>
```