# Scroll de acordo com elemento clicado

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho uma lista de `links`, exemplo:

```
    <ul class="todos-links">
     <li> <a href="#alvo1"> Alvo1 </a> <li>
     <li> <a href="#alvo2"> Alvo2 </a> </li>
     <li> <a href="#alvo3"> Alvo3 </a> </li>
     <li> <a href="#alvo4"> Alvo4 </a> </li>
     <li> <a href="#alvo5"> Alvo5 </a> </li>
     <li> <a href="#alvo6"> Alvo6 </a> </li>
   </ul>
```

E la em baixo, tenho alguns elementos, exemplo:

```
<div id="alvo1">  eu sou o Alvo1 </div>
<div id="alvo2">  eu sou o Alvo2 </div>
<div id="alvo3">  eu sou o Alvo3 </div>
<div id="alvo4">  eu sou o Alvo4 </div>
<div id="alvo5">  eu sou o Alvo5 </div>
<div id="alvo6">  eu sou o Alvo6 </div>
```

A dúvida é: Como faço para clicar em um `link` e realizar um `scroll` até o seu respectivo `alvo`?

Exemplo, clicar no link `Alvo1` e rolar até a `div` com id `alvo1`.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como ir para uma parte de um texto na mesma página clicando num link em cima](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/26005/como-ir-para-uma-parte-de-um-texto-na-mesma-p%c3%a1gina-clicando-num-link-em-cima)

Comment: @hugocsl nesse link, a situação é diferente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim:

```js
$('[href^="#alvo"]').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  let target = this.getAttribute("href")
  $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(target).offset().top}, 1000);
});
```

```css
div {
  margin-top: 500px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="todos-links">
 <li> <a href="#alvo1"> Alvo1 </a> </li>
 <li> <a href="#alvo2"> Alvo2 </a> </li>
 <li> <a href="#alvo3"> Alvo3 </a> </li>
 <li> <a href="#alvo4"> Alvo4 </a> </li>
 <li> <a href="#alvo5"> Alvo5 </a> </li>
 <li> <a href="#alvo6"> Alvo6 </a> </li>
</ul>


<div id="alvo1">  eu sou o Alvo1 </div>
<div id="alvo2">  eu sou o Alvo2 </div>
<div id="alvo3">  eu sou o Alvo3 </div>
<div id="alvo4">  eu sou o Alvo4 </div>
<div id="alvo5">  eu sou o Alvo5 </div>
<div id="alvo6">  eu sou o Alvo6 </div>
```

Você pode ler mais sobre o jquery animate [aqui](http://api.jquery.com/animate).

Comment: Era exatamente isso, eu estava fazendo dessa forma, mas com um objeto selector diferente no evento de `click`. Obrigado!